# Cookie secure tag working on login page but not working after login

Tags: tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

Our web application is running on tomcat version 7. Earlier it's cookie was not having secure tag, so I had modified server.xml to include secure="true" under connector and also modified web.xml to include cookie-config under session-config to include secure and httponly tags.

After the changes I can see that secure tag is coming when I open login page which was not coming earlier but when I login to the site then secure tag again disappears (I have verified this using chrome->cookie section), I can see session id is changing before and after login.

What should I do to keep the cookie secure after login too?

Thanks for your help!!